# Windows NFS client keeps writing read-only with on NFS server with squash_all

Tags: linux, nfs, network-share, nfs4

We have a Debian 8 with an NFS server exported with  `"/client-share    *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)"` that works just fine when transferring files from a Windows machine NFS client. Normally, files are located in the NFS server with the mask permissions of the uid and gid as per the configuration eg:

```
"-rw-r--r--".
```

The problem is that if the file transferred from Windows machine is marked read-only(ntfs), picture:

[image]

Than it breaks the permissions and the file located at the NFS server will have read-only permissions as:

```
"-r-r--r--".
```

The Windows NFS client properties are also configured with the right gid/uid. We have tried using ACLs with setfacl -m "default:group:rwx" /nfs but that doesn't work either. Files are being transferred as 'read-only'.

How can we overcome that?

Answer (score 2):

squash_all has nothing to do with files permissions. It controls only files owner ship. There must be [windows client configuration](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754304.aspx), where you can set default permission for newly created files and directories.

Comment: Quick hint: you need to restart after changing this setting to make it effective.